# Using the Tasks parameter with Registry key entries in Inno Setup script

Tags: inno-setup

I have discussed this task before about file associations. But something just came to my mind.

Here are the task deinifions:

```
[Tasks]
Name: "register32"; Description: "Meeting Schedule Assistant (32 bit)"; GroupDescription: "{cm:FileAssociations}"; Flags: unchecked exclusive; Check: IsWin64
Name: "register64"; Description: "Meeting Schedule Assistant (64 bit)"; GroupDescription: "{cm:FileAssociations}"; Flags: exclusive; Check: IsWin64
```

Here are the registry keys:

```
[Registry]
; ==================================================
; Register File Types
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: ".mwb"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "MeetSchedAssist.MWB"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: ".srr"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "MeetSchedAssist.SRR"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "MeetSchedAssist.MWB"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "Meeting Workbook Schedule"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "MeetSchedAssist.SRR"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "Assignments Report"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "MeetSchedAssist.MWB\Shell\Open\Command"; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\{code:GetExecutableToRegister}"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKCR"; Subkey: "MeetSchedAssist.SRR\Shell\Open\Command"; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\{code:GetExecutableToRegister}"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey
; ==================================================
```

Shouldn't the above registry keys have a `Tasks` parameter? Like this:

```
Root: "HKCR"; \
       Subkey: ".mwb"; \
       ValueType: string; \
       ValueData: "MeetSchedAssist.MWB"; \
       Flags: uninsdeletevalue; \
       Tasks: register32 register64
```

I am just not sure because one one of those tasks need to be ticked by the user, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not put `Tasks: register32 register64` there.

You want those `Registry` entries be processed always, don't you?

On 32-bit system the entries would not be processed, as neither of the tasks exist (due to `Check: IsWin64`).

Your tasks exist only to select the executable (`GetExecutableToRegister`), not to select whether and what keys to create.